# Dynamic import with json file doesn't work typescript

Tags: typescript

So I write a function like this to get test data for multiple environment:

```
export class DataHelper {
  public static async getTestData(fileName: string): Promise<any> {
    return await import(`../${fileName}`);
  }
}
```

this will throw: Error: Cannot find module '../test-data.json'

```
await DataHelper.getTestData('test-data.json')
```

but this will work:

```
await DataHelper.getTestData('TestScript')
```

also this will work:

```
await import('../test-data.json')
```

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "example/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

Can anyone explain what is happening and what should I do instead?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are not actually able to import json files dynamically in TypeScript without the use of import assertions. TypeScript simply allows you to import files with the `json` extension via a configuration property which sadly differs from the JavaScript specification which can be very confusing for many people. Here is how the import assertions look like but they are not currently supported on Node.js:

```
// static import
import data from "./foo.json" assert { type: "json" };

// dynamic import
const { default: data } = await import("./foo.json", { assert: { type: "json" } });
```

TLDR on that is you must assert because the file extension can't be used to determine the file type for security reasons.

Anyways, the best way to get the JSON in Node.js asynchronously is to read the text via `fs` then use `JSON.parse`. At least, until Node.js adds support for import assertions which I would assume not make it for a few years onto stable.

Here's an example:

```
import { readFile } from "fs/promises";

async function readJsonFile(path) {
  const file = await readFile(path, "utf8");
  return JSON.parse(file);
}

readJsonFile("./package.json").then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: It's correctly
`import("./foo.json", { assert: { type: "json" } }).then(module => module.default)`

Comment: why does dynamic return `default`?

Comment: @SalahAdDin There could be other named exports.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Typescript thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53656)

importAttributes "assert" will be no longer supported due to a regression from stage 3 to stage 2.

They are speaking about replacing it by "why" since months.