# Read a JSON file and get JSON object back

Tags: javascript, json, file

I am trying to read a json file into my Javascript program.

**configuration.json**

```
{
    "ProxyURLS": ["xxxx","xxxx"],
    "DatabaseURLS": ["xxxx"]
}
```

The JSON file is in the same directory as the index.html

**Index html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>QUBGrader</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

import { readFile } from "fs/promises";
//Define path for configuration readFile

path = "./configuration"
//read file get json
async function readJsonFile(path) {
  const file = await readFile(path, "utf8");
  return JSON.parse(file);
}

readJsonFile("./package.json").then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
  getProxyURL(data);
});



function getProxyURL(data)
{
  console.log("here")
  console.log(data)
}

... file continues ...
```

I want to obtain the JSON object and pass it to the getProxyURL function.

I get this error when I **do not** include the import statement

```
(index):13 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: readFile is not defined
    at readJsonFile ((index):13:16)
    at (index):17:1
```

I get this error when I do include the import statement

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at (index):8:1)`

From googling the error ([https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-module#:~:text=The%20%22SyntaxError%3A%20Cannot%20use%20import,json%20for%20Node.](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-module#:%7E:text=The%20%22SyntaxError%3A%20Cannot%20use%20import,json%20for%20Node.))

It seems that I need to define a "module", but I am not sure how to do that within a single .html file.

Any help appreciated.

I followed advice from this question: [Dynamic import with json file doesn't work typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70601733/dynamic-import-with-json-file-doesnt-work-typescript)

**EDIT**

After implementing suggested solution:

```
function readJson () {
   // http://localhost:8080
   fetch('./configuration')
   .then(response => {
       if (!response.ok) {
           throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
       }
       return response.json();
   })
   .then(json => {
       getProxyURL(json);
       //console.log(this.users);
   })
   .catch(function () {
       this.dataError = true;
   })
};

readJson();
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: You can't use Node.js modules in a browser. `fs/promises` is a Node.js module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module `fs/promises` is only avaiable in node.js and not in browsers. You should use the `fetch()` api which is supported by all browsers (except very old browsers like Internet Explorer). You can find a documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I get an error. Please see updated question

Comment: Try to type the URL in the browser and look what it returns. Please make sure that the file is available under this location.

Comment: You didn't add the file extension to the file name

fetch('./configuration.json')